# Converting m4a to wav on Android

Tags: android, wav, m4a, mediamuxer

How can I convert audio .m4a to .wav programmatically using [`MediaMuxer`](https://d.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer) and [`MediaCodec`](https://d.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec)? Is it possible?

[image: API]

Comment: better way to use FFmpeg

Comment: You have to decode your .m4a to pcm and add some header to product a .wav file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131595/convert-from-pcm-to-wav-is-it-possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use FFMPEG wrapper for it. Go to https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java link there is a working ffmpeg wrapper for Android. you can easily use it.

Then u can use below command to convert it .m4a to .wav

```
ffmpeg -i <path of inputSong.m4a> <path of outputSong.wav>
```

in the wrapper you don't need `ffmpeg` part. You need to replace it from `-y`. You can get those details when navigate to that wrapper