# How to configure MediaRecorder to record audio in WAV format at 48KHz in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, wav, record

So far I have this: With this code I can configure Media Recorder to record in 3gp, but i need to record in WAV for a later process.

```
private void setupMediaRecorder() {
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(MainActivity.PATH_TEMP_RECORDING);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found it. This configuration works:

```
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(128000);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(48000);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(MainActivity.PATH_TEMP_RECORDING);
```

Comment: not working! where did you find this configuration?

Answer (score 1):

The MediaRecorder do not let you record in the lossless format. Instead, AudioRecord is more low-level API for audio recording, while you need to write buffer code and filewriting code yourself. [Here](https://github.com/aahlenst/android-audiorecord-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/audiorecord/AudioRecordActivity.java) is a example of using AudioRecord to write into .pcm file. WAV is basically a container of PCM [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131595/convert-from-pcm-to-wav-is-it;-possible). If you want to write into .wav, you need to write the header yourself, and [here](https://github.com/vishwakneelamegam/android-wav) is an example of using AudioRecord to write into .wav.